# Java - Compare and Swap and synchronized Block

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

```
public class SimulatedCAS { 
  private int value;

  public synchronized int get() { return value; }

  public synchronized int compareAndSwap(int expectedValue, int newValue) 
  {
  int oldValue = value; 
  if (oldValue == expectedValue) 
      value = newValue;
  return oldValue; 
  }
}

public class CasCounter 
{ 
   private SimulatedCAS value;

   public int getValue() 
   { 
     return value.get();
   }
  
  public int increment() 
  { 
      int value.get(); 
      while (v != value.compareAndSwap(v, v + 1)) 
      {
         v = value.get(); 
      }
  }

}
```

I refereed a Book "Java Concurrency in Practice"

a Counter must be increased by multiple threads. I tried using the compare and swap method but at the end it make used of synchronized keyword which might again result in blocking and waiting of threads. using a synchronized block provides me the same performance can anybody state. what is the difference between using compare and swap and synchronized block ? or any other way to implement compare and swap without using synchronized block.

Comment: You can use `Unsafe.getUnsafe().compareAndSwapInt()` to implement compare and swap. Generally speaking, CAS is more effective than synchronized.

Comment: Why not directly use `AtomicInteger`? No need to do it yourself

Comment: No i can't use Atomic Integer. this is my assigment @Lino-Votedon'tsayThanks

Comment: Unsafe.getUnsafe.compareAndSwapInt() is used in AtomicInteger class. It requires a object and long in additional...  right ? @weaver
How it is different from synchronized block

Answer (score 1):

> I need to increment counter with multiple threads

The [`AtomicInteger` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) is good for that.

You can create it with `final AtomicInteger i=new AtomicInteger(initial_value);` Then you can call `i.set(new_value)` to set its value, and you can call `i.get()` to get its value, and most importantly for your application, you can call `i.incrementAndGet()` to *atomically* increment the value.

If N different threads all call `i.incrementAndGet()` at "the same time," then

- Each thread is guaranteed to see a different return value, and
- The final value after they're all done is guaranteed to increase by exactly N.

The `AtomicInteger` class has quite a few other methods as well. Most of them make useful guarantees about what happens when multiple threads access the varaible.

Comment: is there any other way to do this, without using Atomic Integer ? @Solomon Slow

Comment: @RubanThilak, I don't understand. What is "this" that you want to do? If all you want is for different threads in a Java program to increment the same shared counter, then `AtomicInteger` almost certainly is the best way to do it. The next best, would be something like `synchronized(counter_mutex){counter=counter+1;}`. But, if you are trying to meet specific requirements (e.g., for a homework assignment) then please tell: What are your actual requirements?

Comment: I am sorry for bothering you so much, I need to find the way which gives top performs, without blocking other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Real Compare and Swap does optimistic locking. It changes value and then makes a rollback if something has changed the variable simultaneously. So, if the variable is modified rarely, then CAS performs better, than synchronized.

But if the variable is modified often, then synchronized performs better, because it doesn't allow anything to mess with the variable while it is changed. And so there's no need to make an expensive rollback.

Comment: can compare and swap be performed wthout using syncronized ? @llya Sazonov

Comment: @RubanThilak, There is no pure Java implementation of compare and swap (CAS) that does not lock a lock. The `AtomicXxxxxxx` classes have [`native` implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) that use _platform-specific_ hardware instructions to implement a lock free CAS. You can't access any platform-specific hardware features with pure Java code. That's a consequence of the "write once, run anywhere" philosophy from the early days of Java.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Then whats the difference between just synchronized block and compare and swap. Compare and Swap method uses synchronized which might result in locking the method to one particular thread and forcing other threads to wait.

Comment: @RubanThilak, Are you asking about what they do? They do completely different things. A `synchronized` block is a _block of code_ that no thread can enter without "locking" a mutex, and a mutex is a thing that can only be "locked" by one thread at a time. CAS, on the other hand, is an _operator_ that works on three operands; a variable, an expected value, and a new value. It atomically compares the contents of the variable to the expected value and then sets it to the new value if and only if the current value and the expected value match.

Comment: @RubanThilak, Are you asking about implementation? Your _simulated_ CAS uses `synchronized`, but modern workstation/server/mobile-device CPUs can perform CAS with a single hardware instruction. In fact, it's virtually certain that the mutex that is locked by a `synchronized` block will be implemented _using_ the hardware CAS instruction.

Comment: @SolomonSlow can I make a JNI call to C++ (native) and perform the Compare and Swap operation  without using any synchronized block or synchronized keyword. whether it is possible ?

Comment: @SolomonSlow is there any hardware level instruction i can perform in c++ ?

Comment: @RubanThilak, Well, `+` is a hardware-level instruction. But you probably mean some kind of specialized instruction like CAS. Strictly speaking, No, you can't do that. But in practice, most C and C++ compilers recognize some kind of an `asm` statement. (e.g., https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). An `asm` statement lets you use pretty much any instruction that is supported by the target processor, but when you use `asm`, you probably will lock yourself into compiling the code with one particular compiler, and you'll only be able to run it on one target architecture.

Comment: @SolomonSlow you said CAS is a operator, what you mean by that. the Synchronized CAS function in java can be accessed by multiple thread at same time ?

Comment: @RubanThilak https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming)

Comment: @SolomonSlow let me explain exactly what I want. I need to increment counter with multiple threads using java. I should find a way to avoid other threads waiting for long time. is there any way, I can make a call to JNI and perform the CAS operation. How to implement a CAS using JNI